# Atualização de página após tempo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiz uma página para amostra de dados em tempo real, e necessito de atualização em tempo real após 3 minutos.

Tentei esse código:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 180000);
});
```

Sem resultados.

Não sei se preciso usar o `(document)` para realizar a verificação na certeza de todo o documento carregado, mas dentro da abertura do `ready` pensei que resolveria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Podes fazer isso [só com HTML](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/meta-refresh/):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="180">
```

Onde content é o tempo de espera (em segundos) até ao refresh

Com javascript (nem precisas de jquery), experimenta colocar `window`:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.reload(1);
}, 180000); // 3 minutos
```

Comment: A parte do Meta não podia usar, pela estrutura do meu sistema (Metas ficam em outro lugar, e o tempo é pra uma parte apenas). Mas com o Javascript funcionou. Faltava o `window`.

Comment: Ha ok, mas ficas a saber que podes usar meta noutra ocasião em que aches aplicável. Pois é, faltava o window e eu nem reparei nesse lapso :P . Vou colocar esse acrescento na resposta

Comment: Essa história de faltava `window.` está errada, window é um objeto global, acessivel a todos escopos e não é necessário digitar, o que deve ter ocorrido é que o autor criou alguma variável `var location = xyz;` e isso afetou o escopo atual, menos o global.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é verdade. Bem observado

Comment: Você foi citado aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5719/132 - Convido-lhe a se manifestar.

Comment: Obrigado @VictorStafusa, vou sim

Answer (score 3):

Você tentou aguardar 10 minutos?

600000 milissegundos = 10 minutos.

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 600000); // 10 * 60 * 1000
});
```

Se você quer 3 minutos, tente 180000 milissegundos.

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 180000); // 3 * 60 * 1000
});
```

---

No exemplo abaixo você pode ver o mesmo código sendo utilizado após 3 segundos:

```js
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    $("body").append(" o timeout aconteceu.");
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
Três segundos depois...
</body>
```

Comment: Acabei mostrando de outro lugar que também tem o timeout que não estava funcionando

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino o timeout *em si* está funcionando; eu incluí um exemplo funcional para teste. Seu problema pode ser outro.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino Repetindo, só pra ter enfase: Essa história de faltava window. está errada, window é um objeto global, acessível a todos escopos e não é necessário digitar, o que deve ter ocorrido é que o autor criou alguma variável `var location = xyz;` e isso afetou o escopo atual, menos o global. Ou você está fazendo confusão.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Por ser um sistema legado (mais de 20 anos), deve ter algo perdido usando palavras reservadas mesmo. Não duvido que seja isso.

Answer (score 2):

Pode fazer com `Jquery` também:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000); //tempo em milisegundos. Neste caso, o refresh vai acontecer de 5 em 5 segundos.
});
```

Lembrando que para que isso funcione, você precisa ter o jquery incluído antes da declaração do script.